# How to align anchor tag with button in center

Tags: html, css

I have a button link which I want to align center, horizontally. Here is the code of button-

### HTML:

`<a href="#"><button class="downloadButton">Download</button></a>`


Now, I want to align this in center, please suggest a possible CSS for the same, you can find this fiddle at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/594DY/)

P.S. :- I don't want to use `<center>` tag

Comment: Why use `button` inside an `a`? You can use just `a`. And make `text-align` of parent to `center`. Look this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/594DY/7/).

Comment: @NOX- How did you set width of button to be greater than text written on it?

Comment: By setting `padding` for `downloadButton`: `padding: 7px 20px 8px 20px;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/594DY/8/)**</kbd>

Why use `button` inside an `a`. You can use just `a`. And make `text-align` of **parent** to `center`.

```
<div class="center">
    <a href="#" class="downloadButton">Download</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS of parent:

```
.center { text-align: center; }
```

And set a `padding` for the link:

```
.downloadButton { padding: 7px 20px 8px 20px; }
```

Comment: Amazing.. I like this solution.. I was probably looking for somethink like this one! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
body{ /* or parent element */
    text-align: center;
}
a{
    /* wraps this element according to width of the child element.(here) */
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/594DY/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:
http://jsfiddle.net/594DY/1/

```
a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: this will have some problem ! you need to set the width:150 for the button too.

Comment: @faridzs not really, you can set width: 100% as well, as I show in my fiddle.

Comment: @Jan.J - Not working for me, see image at [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/C7Cnzpj.png) or visit the actual page at [Prateek Singla](http://www.prateek.co.in/2013/05/windows-live-writer-portable-5mb.html)

Comment: First: inline-block and block is not the same. Second: to use auto margin for centering element, you need to set element width < 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to align center the whole button along with `a` tag

```
a {
        width: 150px;
        display: block;    
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Or use this if you want align button center inside `a` tag

```
a {
     width: 100%;
     display: block;    
     text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: -Not working for me, see image at [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/C7Cnzpj.png) or visit the actual page at [Prateek Singla](http://www.prateek.co.in/2013/05/windows-live-writer-portable-5mb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to make a button center:
HTML TAG:

```
<a href="#"><button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Login</span></button></a>
```

And use this CSS, adding some optional style:

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #E80C11;
  border: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```